# Get youtube video thumbnail

Tags: javascript, php, sql, concatenation

I'm trying to get the thumbnail image of a YouTube video from its url, which I get correctly with this script.

```
if ($resulf = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM vid")) {
                while ($rowcontentf = mysqli_fetch_array($resulf)){
                  ?>
                  <a class="angled-img" href="<?php echo $rowcontentf['link']; ?>">
                    <div class="img">
                      
                      <?php
                      // YouTube video url TEST
                      //$videoURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRh_vgS2dFE';
                      $videoURL = '.$rowcontentfinal['link'].';  // YouTube video url SQL
                      $urlArr = explode("/",$videoURL);
                      $urlArrNum = count($urlArr);

                      // Youtube video ID
                      $youtubeVideoId = $urlArr[$urlArrNum - 1];

                      // Generate youtube thumbnail url
                      $thumbURL = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtubeVideoId.'/0.jpg';

                      // Display thumbnail image
                      echo '<img src="'.$thumbURL.'"/>';
                      ?>
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-play icon"></i>
                  </a>
                  <?php
                }
              }
```

But dealing with a very basic example with Database, the URL I get from a SQL query.
But I can't get the video thumbnail from the URL if I get the latter (URL) from my Database.

```
// YouTube video url TEST
//$videoURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRh_vgS2dFE';

$videoURL = '.$rowcontentfinal['link'].';  // YouTube video url SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're accidentally escaping your text by using the same quotes.

Try:

```php
$videoURL = '.$rowcontentfinal["link"].';
```

For this reason, I'd recommend sticking to one quote style for strings and one quote style for "code". eg in he above singles for strings and doubles for "code"

Alternately you can try escaping the internal quotes

```php
$videoURL = '.$rowcontentfinal[\'link\'].';
```